# IIS Files with No Extension

Tags: php, http, iis, get, mime-types

I recently saw a website in which the url was formulated like this:

[http://subdomain.domain.com/script/?var=value](http://www.google.com)

I was wondering how to do this in IIS, and how he put a slash in between the script and the GET variables, and how he had the script with no extension in the first place. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this; I'll describe the simplest.

`script` is a folder containing a file called `Default.aspx` (or whatever is configured as the `Default Document` in IIS)

Therefore, when IIS sees a request to `script/`, it will send the request to `Default.aspx`, which then reads the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of filename defaults to the "index" entry, probably `default.asp[x]` there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is with a URL Rewriter, like [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com), or the  built-in URL Rewriting module that's included with IIS7 and later.

Comment: "It works on IIS 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, and 7.0." - http://iirf.codeplex.com/.

Good thing it works for IIS6, because i have WHS, which is Windows Server 2003. I'll try it.